# How can i open different form pages in C# by login page while collecting data from database

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm making a Grocery store application that connects with a database. I've 3 users at login page Manager Cashier1 and Cashier 2. I want to open form of the relevant user as data is already saved in the database. like when I enter Manager and password of manager it should access Manager pager. when i Enter Cashier credentials it should open Cashier page my code is below thank you.

I'm using C# windows form application.

If it is possible to extract only password field from the database and then compare it with txtUser.text will it work that way or not?

```
    private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=True");
        string query= "select * from ManCash Where USERNAME='"+txtUser.Text+"'and PASS = '"+txtPass.Text+"'";

        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con1);
        DataTable DT = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(DT);

        if (DT.Rows.Count>0&&DT.Rows.Count<=1)
            {
                this.Hide();
                Manager frm4 = new Manager();
                frm4.ShowDialog();
                this.Close();
            }
        else if(DT.Rows.Count>1&&DT.Rows.Count<=2)
            {
                this.Hide();
                Cashier frm5 = new Cashier();
                frm5.ShowDialog();  
                this.Close();
            }
         else if (DT.Rows.Count==3)
            {
                 this.Hide();   
                 Cashier frm5 = new Cashier();
                 frm5.ShowDialog();
                 this.Close();
            }
```

Comment: Don't you have a "Role" column in your ManCash table that provides you the 2 possible roles "manager" and "Cashier" for each login? In this case, use a simple switch on the Role value got from the selected row of the datatable.

Comment: i am at very basic level of this type of coding and very new to MS SQL i do not know about Role column

Comment: Besides "Login" and Password" column, you may add another string column in your table that you can call "Role" (or any other name, if you want).

Comment: Like ID, and how it will help me opening different pages?

Comment: Should i Add primary key ID, or just new field with any name right now my table does not have primary key enabled.

Comment: After SDA.fill(FDT), DT will contain either 0 row (invalid login or password) or 1 row. In that last case, use a switch on  Dt.Rows[0]["Role"] with cases "Manager" and "Cashier".

Comment: ID field is not mandatory. Once added the "Role" column in the SQL datatable, fill the different rows with either "Manager" or "Cashier".

Comment: Like this (DT.Rows[0]["Role"]=="manager") but it is giving an error :) sorry i am at very basic level

Comment: Compile or exec error ? what is the text of the error ?

Comment: @AliHassan I think you should start by reading about authentication and authorization. And how to implement role based authorization in ASP.NET application. Trying to solve the problem after getting knowledge will be better then keep solving the error just because you don't know how to implement it properly.

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0151 A switch expression or case label must be a bool, char, string, integral, enum, or corresponding nullable type 247Grocerystore C:\Users\nokia\Downloads\database\247Grocerystore - Copy2\Login.cs 29 Active

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I don't know how to code in C#, I would like to give you a advice here.

1) Create a new column in your ManCash table and name it 'Role'

2) In your `Role` column, you may make it as a `varchar` or `int` If you made it as `varchar` put `admin`  if it is for the manager, put `staff` if not. And if `int` put `1` for manager and `0` for staff.

3) Create a query similar to the following:

(written in pseudo code)

```
if datatable returns 1 from "Select role from ManCash where username = @username and password = @password" then proceed to next statement
```

4) Retrieve the value from the roles table, that way, you may segregate the pages to be shown like this pseudo code

```
if query returned manager then manager page else staff page
```

5) I suggest you read the basics of Database management, as a developer, you may want to learn how to manage a database, with this knowledge, you'll learn how to make applications faster, more efficient, and secure.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use SQLCOMMAND AND SQLDATAREADER to read the return value of Select statement then put it in a switch statement and make a role for each user. SO that when you login it will automatically match that user on its specific role and open up the exact form.

Comment: Can you please correct it in the code i am not getting it. its my 1st time with SQL. i have added Role in the Table but now how to use it ?

Comment: @AliHassan please do not expect devlopers here to get your work done. Try to understand the problem and logic of it. Read about .NET, ADO.NET, C# and other things which you are working with. Understanding the logic is most important.

Comment: its not about the logic its about syntax as i am very new to it. and 1st time doing coding using c# and SQL i have less knowledge of Syntax

Answer (score 0):

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=True");
    string query= "select * from ManCash Where USERNAME='"+txtUser.Text+"'and PASS = '"+txtPass.Text+"'";
SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand();
cmd.CommandText="query";
cmd.Connection=con1;
con1.Open();
SqlDataReader reader=cmd.ExecuteReader();
Switch(reader["Role"].toString()){
case "Manager":
//redirect to role form
break;
case "Cashier1":
//redirect to role form
break;
case "Cashier2":
//redirect to role form
break;
default:
break;
}
con1.Close();
```

if there's an error , try to fix it with your own i'm just giving the Exact logic to get it done :)

Answer (score 0):

It has worked like this without any error. But thank you all to respond so quickly.

```
    SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=True");

    private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string query= "select * from ManCash Where USERNAME='"+txtUser.Text+"'and PASS = '"+txtPass.Text+"'";
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con1);

        DataTable DT = new DataTable();
        //  SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT Role from ManCash Where USERNAME='" + txtUser.Text + "'and PASS = '" + txtPass.Text + "'", con1);
        // SqlDataReader readr = command.ExecuteReader();
        sda.Fill(DT);

        string a = DT.Rows[0]["Role"].ToString();

        switch (a)
        {
            case "Admin":
                this.Hide();
                Manager man = new Manager();
                man.ShowDialog();
                this.Close();
                break;
            case "Staff":
                this.Hide();
                Cashier ca = new Cashier();
                ca.ShowDialog();
                this.Close();
                break;
        }
    }
```